# Can not burn 1.4GB data into a 4.7GB DVD (file too big)

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, dvd-burning

I'm trying to burn 1.4GB of data into a 4.7GB DVD using Finder in Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard. The biggest file is 300MB.

Here are the steps I take:

- Insert blank disc
- Open Finder and drag files to disc
- Go to File -> Burn

However, I get this error message

> Disc_name is too large to fit on the disc. Remove some files and try again.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a very simple problem in my case. I just have a bad disc. Sorry for wasting the resources here.

Comment: No problem. Please mark your answer as Accepted, so that the question will be closed.